# how to prevent a Python thread from stalling a PyQt GUI

Tags: multithreading, loops, methods, while-loop, pyqt

I'm making a utility for easy control of the usage modes of laptop-tablet devices (i.e., for easy switching between a laptop mode, a stylus writing mode etc.). I am trying to use Python [threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) for a process that continually monitors a particular status in a loop and, if that status changes, it does some things. This monitoring is to run at the same time as a [PyQt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyQt) GUI, however, the GUI never starts and I am not sure why. I would value some guidance on this.

In the code, the method `stylusProximityControl` is being threaded. The code is as follows:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import threading
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import logging

# logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig()
logger.level = logging.INFO

class interface(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(interface, self).__init__()
        logger.info("running spin")
        # engage stylus proximity control
        self.stylusProximityControlOn()
        # create buttons
        buttonsList = []
        # button: tablet mode
        buttonModeTablet = QtGui.QPushButton('tablet mode', self)
        buttonModeTablet.clicked.connect(self.engageModeTablet)
        buttonsList.append(buttonModeTablet)
        # button: laptop mode
        buttonModeLaptop = QtGui.QPushButton('laptop mode', self)
        buttonModeLaptop.clicked.connect(self.engageModeLaptop)
        buttonsList.append(buttonModeLaptop)
        # button: left
        buttonLeft = QtGui.QPushButton('left', self)
        buttonLeft.clicked.connect(self.engageLeft)
        buttonsList.append(buttonLeft)
        # button: right
        buttonRight = QtGui.QPushButton('right', self)
        buttonRight.clicked.connect(self.engageRight)
        buttonsList.append(buttonRight)
        # button: inverted
        buttonInverted = QtGui.QPushButton('inverted', self)
        buttonInverted.clicked.connect(self.engageInverted)
        buttonsList.append(buttonInverted)
        # button: normal
        buttonNormal = QtGui.QPushButton('normal', self)
        buttonNormal.clicked.connect(self.engageNormal)
        buttonsList.append(buttonNormal)
        # button: touchscreen on
        buttonTouchscreenOn = QtGui.QPushButton('touchscreen on', self)
        buttonTouchscreenOn.clicked.connect(self.engageTouchscreenOn)
        buttonsList.append(buttonTouchscreenOn)
        # button: touchscreen off
        buttonTouchscreenOff = QtGui.QPushButton('touchscreen off', self)
        buttonTouchscreenOff.clicked.connect(self.engageTouchscreenOff)
        buttonsList.append(buttonTouchscreenOff)
        # button: touchpad on
        buttonTouchpadOn = QtGui.QPushButton('touchpad on', self)
        buttonTouchpadOn.clicked.connect(self.engageTouchpadOn)
        buttonsList.append(buttonTouchpadOn)
        # button: touchpad off
        buttonTouchpadOff = QtGui.QPushButton('touchpad off', self)
        buttonTouchpadOff.clicked.connect(self.engageTouchpadOff)
        buttonsList.append(buttonTouchpadOff)
        # button: nipple on
        buttonNippleOn = QtGui.QPushButton('nipple on', self)
        buttonNippleOn.clicked.connect(self.engageNippleOn)
        buttonsList.append(buttonNippleOn)
        # button: nipple off
        buttonNippleOff = QtGui.QPushButton('nipple off', self)
        buttonNippleOff.clicked.connect(self.engageNippleOff)
        buttonsList.append(buttonNippleOff)
        # button: stylus proximity on
        buttonStylusProximityControlOn = QtGui.QPushButton('stylus proximity on', self)
        buttonStylusProximityControlOn.clicked.connect(self.engageStylusProximityControlOn)
        buttonsList.append(buttonStylusProximityControlOn)
        # button: stylus proximity off
        buttonStylusProximityControlOff = QtGui.QPushButton('stylus proximity off', self)
        buttonStylusProximityControlOff.clicked.connect(self.engageStylusProximityControlOff)
        buttonsList.append(buttonStylusProximityControlOff)
        # set button dimensions
        buttonsWidth=150
        buttonsHeight=60
        for button in buttonsList:
            button.setFixedSize(buttonsWidth, buttonsHeight)
        # set layout
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        for button in buttonsList:
            vbox.addWidget(button)
            vbox.addStretch(1)  
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        # window
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 150, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('spin')
        self.show()
    def displayLeft(self):
        logger.info("changing display to left")
        os.system('xrandr -o left')
    def displayRight(self):
        logger.info("changing display to right")
        os.system('xrandr -o right')
    def displayInverted(self):
        logger.info("changing display to inverted")
        os.system('xrandr -o inverted')
    def displayNormal(self):
        logger.info("changing display to normal")
        os.system('xrandr -o normal')
    def touchscreenLeft(self):
        logger.info("changing touchscreen to left")
        os.system('xinput set-prop "ELAN Touchscreen" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1')
    def touchscreenRight(self):
        logger.info("changing touchscreen to right")
        os.system('xinput set-prop "ELAN Touchscreen" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1')
    def touchscreenInverted(self):
        logger.info("changing touchscreen to inverted")
        os.system('xinput set-prop "ELAN Touchscreen" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1')
    def touchscreenNormal(self):
        logger.info("changing touchscreen to normal")
        os.system('xinput set-prop "ELAN Touchscreen" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1')
    def touchscreenOn(self):
        logger.info("changing touchscreen to on")
        os.system('xinput enable "ELAN Touchscreen"')
    def touchscreenOff(self):
        logger.info("changing touchscreen to off")
        os.system('xinput disable "ELAN Touchscreen"')
    def touchpadOn(self):
        logger.info("changing touchpad to on")
        os.system('xinput enable "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"')
    def touchpadOff(self):
        logger.info("changing touchpad to off")
        os.system('xinput disable "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"')
    def nippleOn(self):
        logger.info("changing nipple to on")
        os.system('xinput enable "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"')
    def nippleOff(self):
        logger.info("changing nipple to off")
        os.system('xinput disable "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"')
    def stylusProximityControl(self):
        previousProximityStatus = None
        while True:
            proximityCommand = 'xinput query-state "Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen stylus" | grep Proximity | cut -d " " -f3 | cut -d "=" -f2'
            proximityStatus = subprocess.check_output(proximityCommand, shell=True).lower().rstrip()
            if (proximityStatus == "out") and (previousProximityStatus != "out"):
                logger.info("stylus inactive")
        self.touchscreenOn()
            elif (proximityStatus == "in") and (previousProximityStatus != "in"):
                logger.info("stylus active")
        self.touchscreenOff()
        previousProximityStatus = proximityStatus
            time.sleep(0.25)
    def stylusProximityControlOn(self):
        logger.info("changing stylus proximity control to on")
        self.thread1=threading.Thread(target=self.stylusProximityControl()).start()
    def stylusProximityControlOff(self):
        logger.info("changing stylus proximity control to off")
        self.thread1.join()
    def engageModeTablet(self):
        logger.info("engaging mode tablet")
        self.displayLeft()
    self.touchscreenLeft()
        self.touchscreenOff()
        self.touchpadOff()
        self.nippleOff()
    def engageModeLaptop(self):
        logger.info("engaging mode laptop")
        self.displayNormal()
        self.touchscreenNormal()
        self.touchscreenOn()
        self.touchpadOn()
        self.nippleOn()
    def engageLeft(self):
        logger.info("engaging mode left")
        self.displayLeft()
        self.touchscreenLeft()
    def engageRight(self):
        logger.info("engaging mode right")
        self.displayRight()
        self.touchscreenRight()
    def engageInverted(self):
        logger.info("engaging mode inverted")
        self.displayInverted()
        self.touchscreenInverted()
    def engageNormal(self):
        logger.info("engaging mode normal")
        self.displayNormal()
        self.touchscreenNormal()
    def engageTouchscreenOn(self):
        self.touchscreenOn()
    def engageTouchscreenOff(self):
        self.touchscreenOff()
    def engageTouchpadOn(self):
        self.touchpadOn()
    def engageTouchpadOff(self):
        self.touchpadOff()
    def engageNippleOn(self):
        self.nippleOn()
    def engageNippleOff(self):
        self.nippleOff()
    def engageStylusProximityControlOn(self):
        self.stylusProximityControlOn()
    def engageStylusProximityControlOff(self):
        self.stylusProximityControlOff()
def main():
    application = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    interface1 = interface()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

EDIT: [three_pineapples](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1994235/three-pineapples) [highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875728/how-to-prevent-a-python-thread-from-stalling-a-pyqt-gui#comment31326743_20875728) an error in the code. This error has been addressed and the code updated.

Comment: Are any exceptions being raised? It looks to me like the line `buttonsList.append(StylusProximityControlOn)` (and similarly a couple of lines below for turning it off) would raise an exception because StylusProximityControlOn isn't defined. You presumably meant to append `buttonStylusProximityControlOn` (and similar in the lines below)?

Comment: You are quite right. Thanks for spotting that. I have changed the code. There were no exceptions. You can see the GUI starting up simply by commenting out the command ```self.stylusProximityControlOn()``` in the method ```__init__```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally found time to run the code. Simple mistake (you'll be kicking yourself!)

You need to change the line

```
self.thread1=threading.Thread(target=self.stylusProximityControl()).start()
```

to

```
self.thread1=threading.Thread(target=self.stylusProximityControl).start()
```

Note the removal of the parentheses after `stylusProximityControl`. You were effectively asking your method `stylusProximityControl` to run and return a method to give as the target to `threading.Thread`. Of course your method had a `while True` in it so no function was ever returned for the call to `threading.Thread` to launch in a new thread. Hopefully that makes sense to you!

That will get you past your immediate issue, though you will need to think about the use of  `thread.join` (I don't see that the thread will ever join because the loop will never stop). You'll probably want the `while` loop to only loop while some boolean value is True, so that it can clean up the subprocess and exit the loop once the program quits.

Anyway, good luck and I hope you put the development online somewhere (bitbucket or similar) because it looks useful!

Comment: Ah! That's well spotted. Thanks for that! I understand what you mean about the issue of trying to join when the process is stuck in a loop. The immediate solution is to simply kill the process, but I think that proper communications (e.g. queues or pipes) should likely be implemented in order to control the state of that monitoring process. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh - and I've put the utility (which was made for use on my ThinkPad Yoga, but is possibly of use for other tablet-laptop devices) [here](https://github.com/wdbm/spin). I'll be updating it soon with the stylus proximity monitoring capability.

Answer (score 0):

I've advanced towards a solution through the use of [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

I have made the following changes:

- from this: `import threading`

  - to this: `from multiprocessing import Process`
- from this: `self.thread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.stylusProximityControl()).start()`

  - to this: `self.process1 = Process(target=self.stylusProximityControl().start()`
- from this: `self.thread1.join()`

  - to this: `self.process1.join()`

My problem now is getting the multiprocessing process for the proximity control to end when the "X" on the window is selected. This could require both an execution of the method `stylusProximityControlOff()` and possible modification of the method.